# Do not rotate Activity under Activity with "Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" theme

Tags: android, animation

I have activity with complex UI, from this activity I'm starting new one with **Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar** and change background of started activity from Transparent to Black. Then I'm trying to rotate device, and BOTH activities rotating in the same time (because first one thinks that it is still visible), so rotation is incredible slow.

How could I prevent first activity from rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone else will try to do it, my solution is remove  **Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar**, then get screenshot of first Activity and use it as background of second one, instead of making it transparent